# How to block user from doing Factory Reset android

Tags: android, launcher, android-launcher

I am working on a launcher application and my launcher is the only launcher in the tablet. I want to control the users of tablet/application from doing hard reset how can I handle it when my device is Shutdown(or)On . Please let me know if anyone know anything regarding this..?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I actually don't think you can without working on the kernel

Comment: Nothing can stop the user from flashing a custom ROM and screw whatever you've done before. And it is their right to. They own their device, not you.

Comment: @ModularSynth Nothing can stop is not the answer or comment I am looking for I strongly believe every problem has a solution. I feel same for this and second thing is in my case no one is owning/buying  the device we provide the device to facilitate them and want to control the user not to delete the original content thanks for your reply.

Comment: Obviusly you can download the kernel and fit it to what you need, you can fin so tutorials like : https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2110842 but I never tried

Comment: Really. You can't take the ownership of a device. We, the users, don't want you to.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that however you approach this problem.. Nothing can stop a person from flashing a custom ROM and overwrite whatever you have done as @ModularSynth mentioned.

Now let's talk about making your own kernel. I believe you can find guides to what you are looking for and use your modifications in a modified ROM and flash the device with it here : https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2152819

With that said... There is still nothing that can stop a user from taking your device and modifying it unless you can find a way to brick it if it is attempted as a security feature.